# Removing specific characters from a string on ansible

Tags: ansible, regex, ansible-playbook, strings

I have the following

```
- set_fact:
   test_result: " {{ htmlres.content | regex_search('http://website([0-9]+)', '\\1') }}"
```

Using debug, this returns the following `" '[01]'"`

Wanting only the number, I did some experimenting using the `replace()` function and was able to strip the `[ ]` by adding the following:

```
- set_fact:
   test_result: " {{ htmlres.content | regex_search('http://website([0-9]+)', '\\1')
| replace('[','') | replace(']','') }}"
```

My problem now is that the output is now `" '01'` and I can't seem to remove the `'` or the whitespace.

Adding `| trim` to the end for some reason doesn't remove the whitespaces, and adding `regex_search('\'','')` also doesn't seem to escape the character and work.

Am I missing something?

Here's the output from the debug after the first removal:

```
"msg": [
    " '01'",
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking way too difficult. [`regex_search()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) returns an array, and you want the first item.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    test_result: "{{ htmlres.content | regex_search('http://website([0-9]+)', '\\1') | first }}"
```

The blank at the start is the result of your assignment of `test_result`:

```
    test_result: " {{ htmlres.content ...
                  ^-- here
```

Just remove it.

Comment: Wow I didn't even notice the first space. Also thanks for clarifying that it returns an array. It's matching correctly now! Thanks!